# Simple login form using jquery

Tags: jquery

My objective: A login form that accepts a username and password (use admin and password respectively). When used it will populate or create a section in the header that contains a username and the logout option. (this section is not visible when the user is not logged in).

What I have attempted so far is below , which does work but I am wondering how I can improve on this code?

```
<!-- HTML -->
        <div id="first">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="loginusername" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" id="loginpassword" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="button" id="login" value="Sign In" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="second">

        </div>



<!-- JQUERY -->
    $(document).ready(function(){
                // on click Sign In Button checks that username =='admin' and password == 'password'
                $("#login").click(function(){
                if( $("#loginusername").val()=='admin' && $("#loginpassword").val()=='password') {
                        $("#first").hide();
                        $("#second").append("<p>Hello, admin</p> <br/><input type='button' id='logout' value='Log Out' />");
                    }
                else {
                    alert("Please try again");
                }

                $("#logout").click(function() {
                $("form")[0].reset();
                $("#first").show();
                $("#second").hide();
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Does not work? Please explain further. Is there an error or does it not operate as expected? What does the console say (Press F12 then pick console)

Comment: The code does work but can I improve on it?

Comment: what exactly do you want to improve? processing speed does matter? ( which isn't likely )

Comment: Well in a real world sense, hardcoding logins and passwords inside JScript is a bad idea, but I don't know if that's what you mean by improve. This has the look of project/homework about it which is fine, but what specifically do you want to improve? It looks just fine to me.

Comment: your code doesnt work the 2nd time when someone logs out

Comment: Hello hina10531- thanks for your reply. I guess I am just wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A login form is normally used to prevent unauthorized users from accessing informations or actions that should be accessible/allowed only to specific people. So, in order for a login form to do it's job properly, it MUST be secure (as much as possible, at least). If a login form is not secure, it may give the illusion of protecting your data, but skilled people will be able to bypass it without you even knowing it... and this is BAD!

Now, this is the problem I see with a jQuery only login form. The fact that you have the password in plain text in your page code, is just BAD! It is super easy to bypass it! Everyone who will give a look at your page code, will know your admin password. Even if you use good hash algorithms (such as SHA-2) to "hide" the password, it would be almost as bad, since it would give a possible attacker a good hint where to start from to guess your password (using [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) or [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack)).

So, my suggestion is to use a server-side application along with your jQuery script, that may be called through jQuery to check the password and then allow the user in. It is not yet the very best solution (it would be much better to send a password on an https connection), but it is still an improvement!

Your code, in order to do that, should be something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // on click Sign In Button checks with the remote server that username =='admin' and password == 'password'
        $("#login").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/checklogin?user='+encodeURIComponent($("#loginusername").val())+'&pass='+encodeURIComponent($("#loginpassword").val()),
                success:function(data){
                    if(data == "OK")
                    {
                        $("#first").hide();
                        $("#second").append("<p>Hello, admin</p> <br/><input type='button' id='logout' value='Log Out' />");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Please try again");
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $("#logout").click(function() {
            $("form")[0].reset();
            $("#first").show();
            $("#second").hide();
        });
    });
```

You could also change the code to make it send the request through post method (which is slightly better).
On the server side you could have, just to start, a simple script that receives the two get parameters (user and pass), checks if they correspond to the expected values ('admin' and 'password') and prints to screen an `OK` in case of success or a `KO` otherwise. For a simple start you could make a PHP application that does that, like the following (it's a very simple and improvable one, but it's a good starting point):

```
<?php

$user = (array_key_exists("user",$_GET))?$_GET["user"]:""; //Checks if the user parameter has been passed through the get method, if not, sets the $user variable to an empty string
$pass = (array_key_exists("pass",$_GET))?$_GET["pass"]:""; //Checks if the pass parameter has been passed through the get method, if not, sets the $pass variable to an empty string

if($user == "user" and $pass == "pass")
    echo "OK";
else
    echo "KO";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code I think it would help you

```
 <div id="first">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="text" id="loginusername" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input type="password" id="loginpassword" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="button" class="login" value="Sign In" />
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="second">

            </div>




> $(document).ready(function(){
>                 // on click Sign In Button checks that username =='admin' and password == 'password'
>                 $(".login").click(function(){
>                 if( $("#loginusername").val()=='admin' && $("#loginpassword").val()=='password') {
>                         $("#first").hide();
>                          $("#second").show();
>                         $("#second").append("<p>Hello, admin</p> <br/><input type='button' class='logout' value='Log Out' />");
>                     }
>                 else {
>                     alert("Please try again");
>                 }
> 
>                 $(".logout").click(function() {
>                 $("form")[0].reset();
>                 $("#second").children('p, input').remove();
>                 $("#first").show();
>                 $("#second").hide();
>             });
>         });
> 
>     });
```

Comment: Thank you Karan. Thanks everyone for your input. I guess it was a bit of a non-question. Now I know my code is fine. :~)

Comment: if my ans was helpful ,why don't you like that?? :-o